# Installing Ubuntu in a not certified device

Tags: preinstallation

I want to try installing Ubuntu on a 4 year old Dell laptop but it is not listed on the certified devices.

Is it okay to try to install it? or not recommended if not included from the list?
What are the possible consequences that I will encounter?

Please give me some advise.

Thank you!

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

Comment: FYI:   To become a certified device costs $s; ie. it requires people to verify that it works fully and those results to be *certified* so most devices won't be *certified* unless is financially worth it for the makes. The more expensive (enterprise geared) devices are usually safer choices than the *cheaper* consumer geared devices (sold largely on price; thus cheap chips are often included that have support except for the OS they were sold with)